# SaveData in Paraview python is not saving the file

Tags: python, vtk, paraview, openfoam

I used one stl file to split the stl using Paraview. I traced the method using python trace in paraview.

Now, I used the code in python to run it. It runs perfectly, but it does not save the splitted mesh as needed. The code is used as per the trace obtained from paraview. Below is the snipped of the code where SaveData is used to save the file. How to save stl file?

```
import sys  #sys- append path
import numpy as np

ParaViewBuildPath = "/home/ParaView-5.7.0/"
sys.path.append(ParaViewBuildPath + "lib/") 
sys.path.append(ParaViewBuildPath + "lib/python3.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append(ParaViewBuildPath + "lib/python3.7/site-packages/vtkmodules")

from paraview.simple import *   
import vtk
# find source
mesh176_rightstl = FindSource('mesh176_right.stl')
generateSurfaceNormals1 = GenerateSurfaceNormals(Input=mesh176_rightstl)
# Properties modified on generateSurfaceNormals1
generateSurfaceNormals1.FeatureAngle = 15.0
# create a new 'Connectivity'
connectivity1 = Connectivity(Input=generateSurfaceNormals1)

# create a new 'Threshold' 
threshold1 = Threshold(Input=connectivity1)
#threshold1.Scalars = ['POINTS', 'RegionId']

# Properties modified on threshold1
threshold1.ThresholdRange = [10.0, 982.0]

# create a new 'Extract Surface'
extractSurface1 = ExtractSurface(Input=threshold1)

# save data
SaveData('surf176.stl', proxy=extractSurface1, FileType='Ascii')
```

I have addressed the error I am facing from the line "generateSurfaceNormals1".

**[paraview        ]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:713    ERR| vtkPVCompositeDataPipeline (0x556f782fe7c0): Input port 0 of algorithm vtkPPolyDataNormals(0x556f7a16b2a0) has 0 connections but is not optional.**

How to overcome this error?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Regards,
Sunag R A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that `mesh176_rightstl` is None, so the `FindSource` does not find anything. Is the source name correct ? Is the data correctly loaded ?

As an error raised, the script stops and `SaveData` is not called. But its syntax is correct.

Minimal code to test stl writer:

```
s = Sphere()
SaveData('sphere.stl', proxy = s, FileType='Ascii')
```

It correctly produces the stl file with ParaView 5.9

#### edit

You should uncomment the line

```
#threshold1.Scalars = ['POINTS', 'RegionId']
```

Because pipeline is not executed until you ask for (e.g. with the SaveData), no default array can be found when you created the Threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I changed the directory of the mesh file and the error is not there. But the file is still not saving as per SaveData.

I tried the basic one with Sphere as you have suggested. That is working and saving. But no the one I needed.

Comment: I have attached the link to mesh file for reference.

[Mesh](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WhcohfL7Dcl91eUIePLDn4ZYaTJ4sCE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Nico,

Its working correctly now. I uncommented the line, and also changed from "FindSource" to "OpenDataFile" while loading stl file. Many Thanks..!! Cheers..!!

Regards,
Sunag R A.